# App crashes from Play Store on first run - ClassNotFoundException dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-console-developer

App is working fine on Android Studio, but downloaded from Play Store crashes on the first time, then start working fine.

I tried to solve it, but without success (changed minSDK to 21, enabled Multidex).

Build Gradle App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.--------.app"
        minSdkVersion 21                      //Change my min Sdk
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true                // Enable mutlidex
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'      //Multi-dex lib

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'


}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3285)
```

Application Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {                       //Application Class Here

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);                   //OverRide Multidex
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    private Button rate,ad,contact;                //i don't have Application    
                                                  //Using custom Class is this 
                                                  // right way
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
             //My Code
```

Crash Report After Exe Below Code:

```
[Crash Report After Exe Below Code][1]
```

Logcat

```
[Logcat][2]
```

Comment: Please share your application class, is it extended from MultiDexApplication ?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, this could be a MultiDex issue. Try this in your application class. That is in **App.java** which extends **Application**:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Register **App.java** file in **manifest.xml** in the **application** tag. Check below code.

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

Comment: don't have App class only have MainActivity which already extend some other class 
 :(

Comment: You have to implement app class. I'm updating my answer please check it.

Comment: can you check my post again upload my main class

Comment: No need to add in MainActivity class. Just follow my answer to your problem solve. Copy App class and paste it in your app. after that register in App.java class in manifest file.

Comment: can i create my own app App(name).java class because i don't have App class in my files

Comment: Yes. Create your own App class and paste attachBaseContext method.

Comment: Kaushal Panchal  very basic Question but can you help me. Even i create App Activity it extends AppCompatActivity  is their any way declare class that not extends AppCompatActivity  because if i create simple java file then i and unable to declare in  manifest.xml  file   any way to solve this  thanks in advance

Comment: Make simple java class then remove all code and paste my App class.

Comment: In which package you are creating a java class?

Comment: com.Myname.app  where all my Classes present

Comment: As you mention in your 2nd  Comment   "Make simple java class then remove all code and paste my App class"    Simple java can we declare in our manifest.xml file i think not allowed

Comment: o Thanks i just Create App class after implementation of your method mention above  let you know

Comment: Kaushal Panchal still app crash it still crash first launch time then working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Your App class

**UPDATE**

Create New Java File with Any name **E.g. AppClass.java**

in Your new AppClass.java file extend MultiDexApplication.

So your class will look like below.

```
public class AppClass extends MultiDexApplication {

}
```

Now override `attachBaseContext` method.

So finally your complete class will look like below.

```
public class AppClass extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Now you have to Declare your AppClass in **AndroidManifest.xml** file in application tag.

```
<application
     ----------
     ----------
     ----------
        android:name=".AppClass"
     ----------
     ---------->

</application>
```

Comment: don't have App class only have MainActivity which already extend some other class 
 :(

Comment: Chirag Savsani still app crash it still crash first launch time then working fine

Comment: Then post your new CrashLog.